# Changing the app pool managedRuntimeVersion from v4.0 to v6.0

Tags: iis, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to deploy a .NET 6 WebJob to an existing Azure App Service using Azure DevOps.  I updated the App Service from ASP.NET V4.8 to the .NET 6 (LTS) version.

[image]

I installed the ASP.NET Core 6.0 (x64) Runtime extension

[image]

I also verified the .net version in the Azure CLI console:

[image]

Using the Azure App service deploy task in Azure DevOps, I get the following error message

> The application pool that you are trying to use has the 'managedRuntimeVersion' property set to 'v4.0'. This application requires 'v6.0'.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_APPPOOL_VERSION_MISMATCH.  Learn more at: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_APPPOOL_VERSION_MISMATCH.

Can anyone help me understand what I need to do to update the managedRuntimeVersion?  My applicationhost.config file does have v4.0, but I don't have the rights, nor does it seem like the correct fix to modify this directly.  Any ideas how I can update the managedRuntimeVersion, or what else I'm missing here?

[image]

Comment: You need to make sure the server has installed .NET framework 4.5 so that the app pool can use 4.0. Then make sure the application using this app pool not other pools.

Comment: @BruceZhang I'm already using 4.0 and trying to upgrade to 6.0

Comment: The point is not the application pool, but the server making sure that .NET framework 4.5 is installed. If you didnot install 4.5, it is no sense even you set app pool use 4.0.